# (Upgrading Webpack 3 > 4) Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory 'node_modules\ieee754\index.js'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, ieee-754, webpack-4

I'm upgrading from Webpack 3 > 4 and am currently experiencing the following issue when loading a simple page that previously worked without issue:

Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Data\%MYPROJECTDIRECTORY%\node_modules\ieee754\index.js'.

The webpack -w watch files command seems to bundle them without issue. I don't get any other console errors, although there are a few peer dependency issues that i am warned of when doing an npm install, none of them are being used in this particular component I am seeking to render to test the overall upgrade success.

Here are some of my files:

```
//Webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './Scripts/App.js',
    ],
  output: {
    filename: 'Scripts/ReactBundle/bundle.js'
  }, 
  mode: 'development',
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',               
            query:
                  {
                      presets: ['react', 'es2017', 'es2015', 'stage-2'],
                      plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
                  }
        },
      ]
    }, 
    optimization: {
        removeAvailableModules: false,
        removeEmptyChunks: false,
        splitChunks: false,
    }
}

//this was in my Webpack v3 config, but I've removed it for testing.
//resolve: {
//    modules: [
//        "node_modules"
//    ],
//        extensions: ['.Webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx'],
//            mainFields: ["main"]
//},
```

and

```
//package.json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "ASP.NET",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --config Webpack.config.js -w"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "fast-clone": "^1.5.3",
    "fast-levenshtein": "^2.0.6",
    "ieee754": "^1.1.12",
    "material-ui": "1.0.0-beta.30",
    "material-ui-icons": "1.0.0-beta.17",
    "npx": "^10.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-alert": "^4.0.4",
    "react-alert-template-basic": "^1.0.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^3.2.4",
    "react-datepicker": "^2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-draggable": "^3.0.4",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.3",
    "react-pdf-js": "^3.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-resizable": "^1.7.5",
    "react-table": "^6.8.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.4.1",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.3",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "stable": "^0.1.8",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.45",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

I've had limited success researching this issue, but attempted to install the package `ieee754` both globally and locally to no success. I suspect something that was part of my previous config for webpack 3 is screwing up some new defaults in Webpack 4. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I'll add that i can visit the location of the file that appears in the error message and confirm that it does, in fact, exist.

Comment: How did you fix this? I have same problem?

Comment: @erik I never did- the company I was with at the time stayed on webpack 3.